# PHP Arrays - Getting all the related ones based on value

Tags: php, arrays

I have PHP array of arrays as below and I want to extract the arrays based on key "type" value. I mean for example in the below code want to extract based on

```
'type' => '1'
'type' => '2'  ( There are two arrays for this condition)
'type' => '22'  ( There are two arrays for this condition)
```

For this I am going each element in the for loop and combing the related ones . But is there any direct function available to do this ?

some thing like array.search(type value 2) giving the related two entries ..? ( because I have lot of types like this )

Thanks for your help

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'type' => string '1' 
      'code' => string '1'                                                       
      'total_count' => string '200'                                              
      'car_count' => string '4'                                                  
  1 => 
    array
      'type' => string '2'                                                       
      'code' => string '52160'                                                   
      'total_count' => string '100'                                              
      'car_count' => string '2'

  2 => 
    array
      'type' => string '2'                                                      
      'code' => string '26'                                                     
      'total_count' => string '30'                                               
      'car_count' => string '15'  

  3 => 
    array
      'type' => string '20'                                                      
      'code' => string '6880'                                                    
      'total_count' => string '4'                                                
      'car_count' => string '0'                                              
  4 => 
    array
      'type' => string '21'                                                      
      'code' => string '256'                                                     
      'total_count' => string '10'                                               
      'car_count' => string '5'                                              
  5 => 
    array
      'type' => string '22'                                                      
      'code' => string '20'                                                      
      'total_count' => string '100'                                              
      'car_count' => string '8'  

  6 => 
    array
      'type' => string '22'                                                      
      'code' => string '25'                                                      
      'total_count' => string '120'                                              
      'car_count' => string '9'
```

Comment: Do you need to group all elements by their type or just find elements with concrect type?

Comment: I think he wants to group them by key.

Comment: Thanks for your response . Basically client send type code and we have to return the related info to him/her

Comment: Yes if I can group all same types together that also would be great solution .

Comment: There is also requirement showing each type in a separate <div> to the client and the same type in one <div> in the above case two elements of type 22 in one <div> and so in the above case for 7 elements in 5 separate <div>s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can formulate your condition inside a function that returns `true` if an array element matches and `false` if not.

You then use it as a callback with [`array_filter`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_filter).

Example (type must be integer 2):

```
function myMatch($element)
{
    return $element['type'] === 2;
}

$values = array_filter($array, 'myMatch');
```

Modify the function according to your needs. The input will be a single element.

Or if you prefer some interface on your array to be called with a specified constraint ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/w6Xwhv)):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array('type' => '1'),
    array('type' => '2'),
    array('type' => '22'),
);

$compareValue = 'type';
$startsWith = '2';

$array = new OArray($array);

$compareValue = function($v) use ($compareValue)
{
    return (string) $v[$compareValue];
};

$startsWith = function($value) use ($startsWith)
{
    return 0 === strpos($value, $startsWith);
};

$constraint = function($element) use ($compareValue, $startsWith)
{
    return $startsWith($compareValue($element));
};

var_dump(
    $array->filter($constraint)
);

class OArray
{
   /**
    * @var Array
    */
   private $array;
   public function __construct($array)
   {
       $this->array = $array;
   }
   /**
    * function based filter
    */
   public function filter($function)
   {
       if (!is_callable($function))
           throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid function given.');
       return array_filter($this->array, $function);
   }
}
```

But a more elegant variant would be to use a FilterIterator on the array that can take the arguments far nicer and is much more re-useable ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8ZAHde)):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array('type' => '1'),
    array('type' => '2'),
    array('type' => '22'),
);

$filter = new ArrayElementStartsWithFilter($array, 'type', '2');

var_dump($filter->filter());

class ArrayElementStartsWithFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    private $what;
    private $with;
    public function __construct(array $array, $what, $with)
    {
        $this->what = $what;
        $this->with = $with;
        parent::__construct(new ArrayIterator($array));
    }
    public function accept()
    {
       $element = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
       return !empty($element[$this->what])
               && 0 === strpos($element[$this->what], $this->with)
       ;
    }
    public function filter() {
        return iterator_to_array($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling this is not completely fluid. Still wondering how to decouple the element specifier from the contraint, the array filter iterator needs to parameter. It would be nicer to specify the filter function more independent from the subkey parameter... . :)